# How to display Google-map with bubble information using iframe?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for iframe code to display Google-map with address information in bubble  with the height 300px and width 300px.

This is my maps information.
Latitude:64.324498
Longitude:-22.067540

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe
  width="300"
  height="300"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA">
</iframe>
```

You should look at the Google Maps API [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide).